# Second argument to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, allocator

Looking at [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/), I realized that I have never used the second argument when creating vectors.

```
std::vector<int> myInts; // this is what I usually do
std::vector<int, ???> myOtherInts; // but is there a second argument there?
```

Looking at the link above it says that it is for:

> Allocator object to be used instead of constructing a new one.

or, as for [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/):

> Allocator: Type of the allocator object used to define the storage allocation model. By default, the allocator class template for type T is used, which defines the simplest memory allocation model and is value-independent.

I guess it has to do with something with memory management. However, I am not sure how to use that.

Any pointers regarding this?

Comment: This is an example of defining your owm allocator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984588/c-stl-vector-reserve/3984720#3984720

Comment: @skwllsp: that looks interesting. Would you like me to upvote or are you going for the unsung hero badge? :)

Comment: I forgot to add one point. I have used own allocators when I had to find how much memory my containers consumed. I wrote about it a little bit lenghty answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160300/how-to-find-the-memory-used-by-any-object/2160786#2160786

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default allocator, `std::allocator<>`, will handle all allocations made by `std::vector<>` (and others). It will make new allocations from the heap each time a new allocation is needed.

By providing a custom allocator, you can for instance allocate a big chunk of memory up front and then slice it up and hand out smaller pieces when separate allocations are needed. This will increase the allocation speed dramatically, which is good for example in games, at the cost of increased complexity as compared to the default allocator.

Some `std` type implementations have internal stack-based storage for small amounts of data. For instance, `std::basic_string<>` might use what is called a *small string optimization*, where only strings longer than some fixed length, say 16 characters (just an example!), gets an allocation from the allocator, otherwise an internal array is used.

Comment: but in `std::vector<int>`, doesn't the `int`s end up on stack?

Comment: @Default - no. std::vector (by default) allocates its storage on heap.

Comment: @Default: Please see my addition about *small string optimization*.

Comment: @Johann Gerell: thanks. This is the best answer so far, I'm holding it open a bit longer if more answer drop in.

Comment: @Johann, @atzz: `std::vector` by default _dynamically allocates_ its elements. There is no guarantee what data structure this allocation uses.

Comment: @Tomalak: *There is no guarantee what data structure this allocation uses* - did I say there was?

Comment: @Johann: Yes. You said "the heap" and "stack".

Answer (score 2):

Custom allocators are rarely used in general case. Some examples of where they can be useful:

- Optimization for a specific pattern of allocations. For example, a concurrent program can pre-allocate a large chunk of memory via standard means at the beginning of task execution and then shave off pieces off it without blocking on the global heap mutex. When task is completed, entire memory block can be disposed of. To use this technique with STL containers, a custom allocator can be employed.
- Embedded software, where a device has several ranges of memory with different properties (cached/noncached, fast/slow, volatile/persistent etc). A custom allocator can be used to place objects stored in an STL container in a specific memory region.

Comment: So basically, I might as well ignore it until I need to worry about memory management :)

Comment: @Default - basically, yes. On a different note, you may have to take into account the presence of second parameter when passing an STL container template as a *template template parameter* to other template. But normally it's not a frequent situation too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079

You may try google for: *stl allocator*.

Answer (score 1):

[Allocators (STL)](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079) help you to manage memory for your objects in vector class. you may use the custom allocator for different memory model( etc).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find example of custom allocator http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/allocator.aspx